# Can I stop google bot from trying to request google map static images?

Tags: html, image, google-maps-api-3, googlebot

I have an `<img>` tag on a series of html pages.

Each href is of the form `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?...`
Access to these images by 3rd-parties is blocked (by design) by Google which is fine by me.

In my server log I have a series of errors generated by the Googlebot for each request it makes to this image URLs.

I'd prefer to avoid generating HTML specific to bots so let's put that option to one side.

Are there any non-JS solutions for giving bots a hint not to request these images?

Failing a non-JS solution, is there a JS solution?

Comment: This makes no sense... the Googlebot's failed requests to maps.googleapis.com can't be showing up in your logs.

Comment: In my site's App Engine logs, I have an "!!" entry and the text https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:red%7Clabel:A%7C30.245636,-97.8049112&zoom=12&size=600x400&maptype=roadmap&key=XXXXXX - I've not quoted my key.